# rsync expanding remote directory with local username?

Tags: linux, rsync, 32-bit, debian-wheezy

I am new to rsync but attempting to setup a backup server.

User names follow this basic idea:

```
remote user: computer
local user: computer-bkup.
```

When I run

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh computer@computer.somewhere.com:$HOME/bar/ $HOME/Documents/foo
```

and enter the password for `computer` I get

```
rsync: change_dir "/home/computer-bkup/bar" failed: No such file or directory.<br>
```

I've looked into file permissions and other related posts for this error. Here's where my head gets twisted though. My `src` directory is `/home/computer/bar` with a source of `/home/computer-bkup/foo`. If the error message had a problem with either of those I can see a permission issue. An error with `/home/computer-bkup/bar` tends to make me think it's trying to find `/home/computer-bkup` on the remote machine.

As that doesn't make sense where do I most likely have issues? Permission on local machine, remote machine or something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $HOME variable is expanded by the shell on the local machine. So, both $HOME are replaced by /home/compute-bkup/ (the home directory of the local machine). You must replace the first $HOME by /home/computer/

Note:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh computer@computer.somewhere.com:bar/ $HOME/Documents/foo
```

will also work, because the default remote path is the home directory